# Reference of a word

Tags: grammar, reference

Does the word **throbbing** here refer to the sun, or to the speaker herself? I always confront similar problems, so, are there any rules I should follow?
thank you.

O Love, Love, Love! O withering might!

O sun, that from thy noonday height

Shudderest when I strain my sight,

Throbbing thro' all thy heat and light,

Lo, falling from my constant mind,

Lo, parch'd and wither'd, deaf and blind,

I whirl like leaves in roaring wind.

Comment: It sounds as if Love, the Sun and the poet are all intentionally mixed up there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
My Impression is that the poet says that he is " throbbing through the heat of the Sun, which is Love,  then falling from his constant mind, and all that happens when he is whirling" . is that right?

Comment: This is probably answerable,  but why do you choose this kind of poem for learning English?  Poets intentionally play with language, sometimes bending it, sometimes breaking it. They just aren't much use for basic questions of grammar or reference, since the literal meaning may be quite different from the *intent*.

Comment: Didn't anyone feel inclined to note that this is from the 1833 poem _Fatima_ by Alfred, Lord Tennyson? It [has been called](https://toomanybooksspoilthebroth.wordpress.com/2015/03/03/fatima-alfred-lord-tennyson/) 'an explicit discussion of sexual desire and longing'.

Comment: I do not think that the 'poet' is throbbing about anything, or at least only in an artistic way. The words are (of course) written by a man, (Lord Tennyson) but they are, in the poem, those of a woman, Fatima, who is expressing her passion for a (male) lover.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty _It sounds as if Love, the Sun and the poet are all intentionally mixed up there_ - that's poetry for you!

Comment: @JamesK - At school I was force-fed a diet of Tennyson, although they didn't include this one, perhaps for obvious reasons, and I can't say it has done me much harm.

Comment: I don't think this is about the sun in the sky, and the 'throbbing' thing is certainly not celestial, at least not literally. I am tempted to write a little answer, if people don't think that poetry interpretation is wildly off-topic.

Comment: @JamesK Thanks for your reply.
Yes, You're absolutely right, but I Just Love to read English Poetry, it develops me spiritually.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks for your reply. Yes, I know it is of Tennyson, and surely the speaker is a woman called Fatima, that's why I wrote "herself" in the main question. so since "throbbing" is not a celestial thing, it would be a human thing, and who is throbbing here is Fatima, under the heat of the Sun, Which is obviously Love.